# Qual è il significato di "giuntare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> A Emilio non so, e poi lui avrebbe avuto sempre piú poco a che fare con la casa, ma a me questo comandare di Stefano mi mise dentro un affanno, quasi un presentimento che alla fine ci **avrei giuntato**. Stefano ci aveva già comandati, tra lui e me che ero il secondo c’erano cinque anni di diversità, ma sopra di lui restava sempre nostro padre; adesso il comando tutto nelle sue mani non mi lasciava per niente tranquillo.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "alla fine ci avrei giuntato" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato il verbo "giuntare" in alcuni dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere molto senso in questo contesto.

Comment: Giuntare nel dialetto piemontese significa rimettere, nel senso di perdere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giuntare nel [dialetto piemontese](http://alessandrialisondria.altervista.org/dialet-lissandren-dizionario-alessandrino-italiano/) significa rimettere, nel senso di perdere:

> giuntè (v. tr.). giuntare. * Al rifl. giuntèji = rimetterci

e da Treccani per [rimettere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rimettere/):

> 9. Assai com., nell’uso fam., rimetterci, scapitare, perdere: *fatti tutti i conti ci ho rimesso cinquecento euro*;

La frase indicata nel contesto da te citato può essere intesa così:

> ma a me questo comandare di Stefano mi mise dentro un affanno, quasi
>   un presentimento che alla fine ci avrei **rimesso**.

Comment: Quindi, "rimetterci" nel [senso **9** del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rimettere)?

Comment: Esatto. Per favore correggi il link del commento

Comment: Che questo modo di dire derivi dal fatto che chi ci rimette deve appunto _mettere una giunta_ ovvero _aggiungere_ qualcosa al già dato? O la mia è solo una speculazione campata per aria?